# Spring Cloud Contract and Spring-WS Endpoints

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Can Spring Cloud Contract be used to test Spring Boot services that are running Spring-WS Endpoints? I would like the ability to define SOAP requests/responses using the Groovy DSL, but I haven't been able to get these services to work with Spring Cloud Contract. I keep getting a failure (expected 200 but received a 404) when I try to run these tests. Interestingly, I added  @RestController and @RequestMapping annotations to my Endpoint class (knowing it wouldn't work) just to test whether or not the fact that these services are Spring-WS endpoints and not Spring REST controllers may be the problem (i.e., does Spring Cloud Contract only "see" REST endpoints?). And...I moved on to a different set of errors. So, I am assuming at this point that I can not use Spring Cloud Contract to test my SOAP services, but I would like to know for sure (i.e., is there some way to do this that I haven't discovered yet?).

Our core services are implemented as REST services, but we still have to support our SOAP clients until they can migrate to REST, so they wrap our REST services. I need the ability to test both. I have successfully created tests for our REST services.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the explicit mode to make rest assured send real request. In the base class you'll have to setup the whole application so that it bindd to a real port. Then in the before section of your test you need to tell rest assured that I'd should call the following port. And that's it :P

Comment: Will the Spring-WS service still be able to make use of the stubs for other services that Spring Cloud Contract generates? Or, will I have to have the full stack up and running (e.g., OAuth service, service dependency A, service dependency B, etc.)?

Comment: It all depends on you. In the base class you can start a normal Spring Context. My suggestion is to (on the producer side) stub any subsequent calls outside your controller. You don't want to do end to end testing in your contract tests. In other words if your controller calls a service you should stub out that service in your contract tests. On the consumer side you can call as many stubs as you want to. Of course these are my assumptions towards Spring-WS cause I've never tried it with Spring Cloud Contract.

Comment: I don't want to have to manually create stubs for the dependencies, as that defeats the whole purpose of using Spring Cloud Contract where the dependency stubs only get generated if the tests that produce them pass. Are you saying that's what I would have to do, manually create these stubs for the service dependencies? If not, how can I use the stub jars that were generated by Spring Cloud Contract to mock the service dependencies in this kind of setup?

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. When I say you can call as many stubs == in stub runner you can pass as many artifact ids as you want to.

Comment: The producer defines the contracts - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer/src/test/resources/contracts/beer/rest and the consumer asks for them in its tests - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/consumer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerControllerTest.java#L28

Comment: I can do that on the producer side?

Comment: On the producer side, in the producer side contract tests, you don't want to call any external services. If however your producer is also a consumer then it can call other services. For the producer you should stub out all calls to any services like here - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerRestBase.java

Comment: Are there any plans for Spring Cloud Contract to support XML request formats?

Comment: Not really cause wiremock doesnt support xpaths with regex. Thats why we havent invested our tine in this feature